# Exporting layout in .pdf A3 size using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, export, pdf, layouts

I am using PyQGIS with GGIS 3.

I'd like to export my map in a A3 size .pdf (so that my printer prints it directely in A3).

How do I do that?

I did not find the right settings for exporting the pdf.

```py
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('Example')
pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.page(0).setPageSize('A3', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Landscape)

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)

pdf_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
pdf_settings.dpi = 300
#pdf_settings.papersize = 'A3'  --> is there something alike?

exporter.exportToPdf(result_folder +"\\myA3.pdf", pdf_settings)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following to change the first page of your layout to A3 landscape:

```
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('Example')
pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.page(0).setPageSize('A3', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Landscape)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and my .pdf is now A3. However, my template now does not fit anymore (see edits). Is there a trick to make everything A3 in one go?

Comment: Of course! You have to change the size of your objects "map", "legend" .. ! it's not magic

Comment: As @FranRaga mentioned, I don't think there is a setting which automatically stretches the items in the layout to fill out the space. You need to specify the position and size using something like: `map = layout.itemById('map')`; `map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))`; `map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(200, 100, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))`

Comment: ok that's sad ;-) Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

you need change this property in the page **layout**, not in **pdf** setting.

I add a proof of concept:

```
page = QgsLayoutItemPage(layout)
page.setPageSize('A3')
```

Comment: I added these two lines under my: layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('Example') and it did not work :-S

Comment: The complete example is that of @Joseph